# why does the genericity of class effect the genericity of method

Tags: java, android

```
public class Test {

public void test(){
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    TextView textView = demo.getView(1);
}


class Demo {

    private View ContentView = null;

    public <T extends View> T getView(int id){
        return ContentView.findViewById(id);
    }
}

}
```

The above is no problem.The following compilation fails, requiring a strong wall conversion type

```
public class Test {

public void test(){
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    TextView textView = demo.getView(1);
}


class Demo<B> {

    private View ContentView = null;

    public <T extends View> T getView(int id){
        return ContentView.findViewById(id);
    }
}

}
```

I just added a generic type of the class and had to force it when calling getView ().why?thanks

Comment: What? You obviously added a generic type to a method and not to a class. Besides, your two code examples are identical.

Comment: I can't spot the difference between source 1 and source 2.

Comment: @minus `class Demo<B>` the generic `B` is the difference

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko now I see it ... but it has been edited since I wrote my comment.

Comment: @minus before edit it was `Test<B>`

Comment: Yes, I just edited it. Why do we need to overtype when we add a generic class?

Comment: In the second example, `demo` has a raw type, and raw types erase all generics, even those unrelated to the omitted type parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner you should post it as an answer, it is truly an interesting and general question, and interesting answer.

Comment: @minus it is quite adequately covered in the dupe. It's not necessarily easy to find that question, if you were looking for it by yourself, but that's why dupes are shown in a big yellow box.

Comment: @minus but yes, it's an interesting thing that catches a lot of people out. At one point, I remember dupe-hammering this question roughly once a week.